# Getting H6 tags in nested content_tag in helpers - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I'm using the following code to get H6 tag in the helper method with content_tag

```
content_tag :div, :class => "meet_list" do
 content_tag(:h6, "Hello world!", :class => "shadow")  
  content_tag :div, :class => "list_wrap" do
  end
end
```

But the H6 tag is not working when used with nested content_tag.
Please advise

Comment: It looks like there's either something wrong with your indentation or your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any real reason why you not simply use regular HTML in the .erb file (I assume you are using erb)?

I would not go to great lengths to avoid using normal markup especially for markup tag generation (links and form elements are something different).

In your case you could just write:

```
<div class="meet_list">
  <h6 class="shadow">Hello World</h6>
  <div class="list_wrap">
  ..
  </div>
</div>
```

Comes down to taste I guess - but abstracting away the HTML doesn't buy you a whole lot right there.